# How can I add a dynamic button in ASP.NET with db data in a foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website for the school. I am making a shop with db products. I made, in a foreach loop, a button for all my products. For each button, I need to save data in my char at that specific product. I did something wrong. Please help me.

```
public partial class OrderFood : System.Web.UI.Page
{     
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillPage();            
    }

    public void FillPage()
    {
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        List<Product> products = productModel.GetAllProducts();

        if (products != null)
        {
            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                Panel OFood = new Panel();
                Image img = new Image();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblDetail = new Label();
                Label lblPrice = new Label();
                Button btn = new Button ();
                DropDownList ddamount = new DropDownList();

                //amount
                int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
                ddamount.DataSource = amount;
                ddamount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddamount.DataBind();
                btn.ID = "s";
                img.ImageUrl = "~/AdminManagement/FoodImages/" + product.Image;
                img.CssClass = "img-rounded3";
                ddamount.CssClass = "form-control";
                lblName.Text = product.Name;
                btn.CssClass = "btn-success btn";
                btn.Text = "comanda mancare";
                lblDetail.Text = product.Desctiption;

                lblPrice.Text = "Lei:  " + product.Price;
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3'>" });

                OFood.Controls.Add(img);
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<h3>  " });
                OFood.Controls.Add(lblName);
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</h3>" });
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                OFood.Controls.Add(lblDetail);
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<h4>  " });
                OFood.Controls.Add(lblPrice);
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</h4>  " });
                OFood.Controls.Add(ddamount);
                OFood.Controls.Add(btn);
                OFood.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "</div>" });

                // add dynamic panels to static parent panel
                OFoodP.Controls.Add(OFood);

                btn.Click +=delegate
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                    {
                        string clientId = "-1";
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                        int AMount = Convert.ToInt32(ddamount.SelectedValue);

                        Cart cart = new Cart()
                        {
                            Amount = AMount,
                            ClientID = clientId,
                            DatePurchased = DateTime.Now,
                            IsInCart = true,
                            ProductID = id,
                        };

                        CartModel model = new CartModel();
                        lblResult.Text = model.InsetCart(cart);
                    }
               };
           }
        }
        else
        {
            //no products found
            OFoodP.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "no food found" });
        }
    }       
 }
```

Comment: What is the error? Where is the error? What have you tried to do to solve it?

Comment: i made an button to stare in cart my products and button dosen`t work

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a `DataGrid`. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/) you can see an example.